# Insert custom metatag in all the internal pages of the site, less in the homepage

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

I would like to insert these metatags, in all the internal pages of the site, less in the homepage

I wanted to inform google to only `index` my homepage, I wanted to insert this conditional in the `head.php` of my genesis installation.

```
<meta name = "googlebot" content = "noindex, noarchive, follow" />
```

I tested this code below but it did not work

```
if ( is_home() ) {

} else {
    <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex,noarchive,follow"/>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use this code.

```
<?php !is_home() : ?>
    <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex,noarchive,follow"/>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Keep in mind you are using `php` and you want to put some HTML within. You cannot simply write down everything like that.